# how i can create multi image with different Location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how i can create 14 image with different Location ( Random Location ) in html using javascript ?

this is my code

```
function createAliens() {

        $('body').append('<img class="alien" src="alien.ico" width="70" height="70">');
```

}

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://fiddle.jshell.net/ju81o1zn/1/  (code is not absolutely perfect but coul show you a direction). you will need to check for the height and width of the images and place them correctly, so that the full img is visible when placed near the document border and deal with overlaying images. (did it vanilla)

Comment: Here with function https://fiddle.jshell.net/ju81o1zn/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to use html canvas and access the coordinates properties of it, and then properly add your objects to that layout

Comment: without using canvas any other solution ؟